If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component and it has 'showClear' input, then verify that it is part of this module
I am trying to run npm run build in azure pipeline, but I am getting an error on primeng components
1. If 'p-dropdown' is an Angular component and it has 'showClear' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-dropdown' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. <p-dropdown [options]="users" formControlName="selectedUser" placeholder="Users" optionLabel="name" [showClear]="true" styleClass="w-full md:w-15rem"></p-dropdown>

I have added CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA and NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to my module and I am running Angular version 18 with node 20.x. I am getting error only in azure pipeline build.
How to fix the azure pipeline build in order to solve the above problem?

Does it work locally? Did you import DropdownModule in your component?

Yes I have imported and it works locally

Hi @Gopala, according to your description, it works on the local but failed in the pipeline. Could you please try to configure a self-hosted agent on your local to run the pipeline? This way we can narrow down if the issue is related to the agent environment.  Also, you can enable the system.debug to check if there are more details in the debug log.

If possible, can you please create and share a Minimal, Reproducible code example and the YAML you are using to better troubleshooting the issue?  By the way, I found the same error issue for your reference.

I created a self hosted agent and ran the pipeline and it works in the self hosted pipeline how can we figure out what's the environment difference between both the agent?

Hi @GopalaKrishnan, please check the answer I shared some steps to figure out the environment difference between the agents for your reference.

Hi @GopalaKrishnan, have you figured out the environment difference between the agents?

This may help:
1.Ensure DropdownModule is imported in your Angular module or your standalone
component

In azure-pipelines.yml:

Use Node.js 20.x
Run npm ci to install dependencies
Clear npm cache if needed


Update PrimeNG to latest version compatible with Angular 18.

Add --verbose flag to build command for more error details.

Include PrimeNG types in tsconfig.json.

Use correct production build configuration in pipeline.


If these don't work, review your full azure-pipelines.yml, Angular module file, and complete error log for more specific troubleshooting.

The above steps didn't work still getting the same error, I have configured the pipeline to the same configuration as my local

According to your comment, the same pipeline works in the self-hosted pipeline but failed in the Microsoft agent.
To figure out what's the environment difference between both the agent, please try the following steps:

Compare Software:
You can find the included Software link for each Microsoft-hosted agent image here and compare the installed software with your self-hosted agent.
Please make sure the versions of Node.js and npm are the same on both agents. You can check the versions using: node -v and npm -v.
If your project relies on specific dependencies or configurations, ensure that these are installed and configured identically on both agents.

Compare Environment Variables:
Run a script on both agents to output all environment variables. This can help you spot differences in configurations.
Example PowerShell script for Windows: Get-ChildItem Env: | Sort-Object Name
Example bash script for Linux: printenv | sort

Compare Build Logs:
Compare the build logs from both agents to identify any differences. You can enable the system.debug to check if there are more details in the debug log. The number of log lines is usually large, and you might consider using some comparison tools to help you effectively identify differences.

Network and Permissions:
If your build process involves accessing external resources, please make sure that both agents have the same network access and permissions.


